# How to validly encode a numerical target variable in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to get Scikit-learn working with a classification problem for a data set with 500 observations, 20 features, and 5 categorical target labels (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). The features are all of type float64, and they have been normalized to z-scores. The fitting and validation works fine, as long as the target variable (y) is fed as a one-dimensional NumPy array.

However, I recently realized the importance of one-hot encoding the target variable, since the outcome of the classificiation seems to slightly vary depending on the integer a class is assigned.

For example, here's a quick overview of the mean results for a k-NN classifier by using different orders for the encoded variables:
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) = 52,7%,
(2, 4, 6, 8, 10) = 52,5% and
(4, 3, 5, 1, 2) = 52,1%. This is problematic, since the labels for y are originally strings, and the integers themselves don't tell anything about the data.

One way to solve this problem would of course be to feed y as string values (e.g. "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"). However, I found out that scikit-learn automatically converts strings to integers, as long as the values are convertable to integers. This does not eliminate the problem itself, since ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5") would still result in a mean accuracy of exactly 52,7%. Using values like ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e") could be a solution, but it results in the error message:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Unlike in Keras, it appears that the target variable has to be fed as a one-dimensional NumPy array, and thus, can't be given as a one-hot encoded matrix with the shape (500, 5). This results in the following error message:

ValueError: bad input shape (500, 5)

Here's an example of the code for a simple Gaussian Naive Bayes model:

```
random_state = 123
n_splits = 10
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits, random_state=random_state,
shuffle=False)

model = GaussianNB()

for train, test in cv.split(X, y): 
    y_dummies = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
    y_dummies = y_dummies[:, 1:]

    X_train, X_test = X[train], X[test]
    y_train, y_test = y_dummies[train], y_dummies[test]

    model.fit(X_train, y_train) 
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

    conf = confusion_matrix(y_test.argmax(axis=1), y_pred)
    print(conf)
```

In the end, I would like to be able to output the confusion matrix (conf), that has eliminated the effect of the abstract numeric label that were assigned for each of the five classes.

Comment: It's strange, because K-NN is not using the label in any way in the model calculation (not like a neural network, in which a one hot encoding works just fine), apart to check if the instance is correctly classified in the neighborhood

Answer (score 0):

When using K-NN the way in which you represent the classes/target labels would not influence the accuracy/precision/recall all other metrics that you are using to evaluate the model

Since you classify an instance as correctly classified if the majority of the k nearest neighboors are of the same class of the instance

I think that there is some other problem in your implemantation. Maybe there is some shuffle or other random sampling on your dataset before the evaluation is done (which of course would impact, slightly or a lot, depending on the size of your dataset, your performance).

Or maybe you are not consistently modifying your labels when doing the changes